On a dual boot computer, keyboard occasionally does not work on Grub menu
I recently installed Ubuntu 22.04LTS alongside Windows 10 on my machine (HP EliteDesk 800 G2 SFF) in a dual-boot configuration. When I start the computer, I find that the keyboard is frequently unresponsive in the Grub menu, which forces me to select Ubuntu after a few seconds. Other times, I find that the keyboard is working on the Grub menu. So far, I have not been able to discern a clear reason why this happens.
I went into the BIOS settings on my machine, and found that I have two identical "ubuntu" entries in my boot order list, along with Windows Boot Manager. I played with the boot order and I put both "ubuntu" entries at the top of the list. I found that changing the order of the "ubuntu" entries seems to temporarily resolve the issue. But I reset the machine and few times to test switching between Ubuntu and Windows, and found that the problem reappears.
A few more details:

The machine is a desktop computer, and I'm using a USB keyboard connected to one of the USB3.0 ports at the back of the machine.
I have seen forum entries which suggest removing duplicate entries using efibootmgr, However, when I run efibootmgr -v on the terminal, I only see one "ubuntu" entry in the list: /File(\EFI\ubuntu\shimx64.efi).
When I tested resetting the machine to switch between Windows 10 and Ubuntu, several times I noticed that the boot order I had set in the BIOS had been altered from what I had set it to.
I am using Grub 2.06.

Any help resolving this issue would be appreciated!

A long shot. I am using a HP Prodesk 600 G3 MT PC. I seem to remember that the first USB (top) on the front was special in some way with regard to the BIOS & keyboard. (I can't find the reference now though.) Anyway, try the keyboard plugged in there.
